# How to find a value after a particular string and print it other file

Tags: perl

I am matching a string in one file and want to print the value written after that string in certain file. Here is the code which I tried. It runs well but didn't produce any output

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $file, "<", "abc.txt") || die ("Cannot open file.\n");
open(my $out, ">", "output.txt") || die ("Cannot open file.\n");

while(my $line =<$file>) {
chomp $line;
if ($line =~ /xh = (\d+)/) {
print $out $_;
}
}



abc.txt
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 d = 4 
+xh = 10 e = 9 f = 11
+some lines
+xh = 12 g=14
+some lines
some lines
+xh = 13 i=15 j=20
some lines   


output.txt
10
12
13
```

Please suggest to improve my code. There is a "+" sign before every xh, and there is a white space before and after every "=" sign. I need to print every value of xh in other file. There is a "+" sign at the beginning of few lines. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Printing `$_` doesn't make sense, as it's not used anywhere, so you want to check content of `$1` captured group,

```
print $out $1;
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Comment: @Сухой27..I clicked on this link...I try to run it but its showing "Language must not be blank"

Comment: @Сухой27.. Its perfectly working there...but when I run on my system then it doesn't show any output neither on command prompt nor in output file...I am working on ubantu

Comment: @Сухой27...This code is working fine...can you share your mail id so that I can send my actual files there...

Answer (score 1):

Сухой27 has already answered your answer. In reference to your below statement:

> There is a "+" sign before every xh, and there is a white space before
>   and after every "=" sign. I need to print every value of xh in other
>   file. There is a "+" sign at the beginning of few lines.

You could modify your regex to `\+xh = (\d+)`

Comment: ...I have already tried this and it shows the error....Quantifier follows nothing in regex;marked by Here in m/+

Comment: That's what the backslash is for. It escapes the meta character.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "$1\n" if /xh = (\d+)/
}


__DATA__
abc.txt
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 d = 4 
+xh = 10 e = 9 f = 11
+some lines
+xh = 12 g=14
+some lines
some lines
+xh = 13 i=15 j=20
some lines
```

Comment: @fugu...this is working perfectly...but my actual input file is huge one...and what i need to match is something different and it is not working.  Line I need to match is +vth0    = 10......the value of vth0 is in multiple lines...so I need to save all the values in a single file. I have tried alot to match this string but its not working...What I wrote is /\+vth[0]=(\d+)/...and i tried other combinations also..there is at least 4 spaces between vth0 and =, one space between = and 10...can you share your mail id?

Comment: @Suhan You should ask another question

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is fine, but there is nothing in `$_`. A capture doesn't set `$_`, it sets `$1`, `$2` and so on.

So your code should read:

```
while(my $line =<$file>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ m/xh = (\d+)/) {

               # here
    print $out $1;
  }
}
```

See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @simbabque...didn't work...same problem...code runs well but didn't get anything in output file